# MariaDB/ mySQL grouping nested SQL results doesn't work as in MSSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, mariadb

I think I do not understand how nested queries in MariaDB (/mySQL) get resolved.
This query works as expected in MSSql, but not in MariaDB:

```
SELECT 
    V.mac,
    V.time_grouped,
    MIN(V.distance) AS mdist
FROM (      
    SELECT 
        mac,
        distance,
        rectime,        
        TO_SECONDS(rectime) - MOD(TO_SECONDS(rectime),5)  AS time_grouped
    FROM myData
) V 
GROUP BY V.mac,
    V.time_grouped;
```

I want to group timed events into 'slots' of 5 seconds. I calculate a field 'time_grouped' to provide such slots. The field 'time_grouped' only holds values being multiples of 5, i.e. ending with 0 or 5. => Works fine.

Now I want to group the resulting data by this value, ie I want to to find the minimum distance of a mac in a 5-sec slot. Obviously all values of V.time_grouped again should be multiples of 5. => They are not.

So I think that the query optimizer doesn't handle my query in the expected way.
(I use those kind of queries frequently (and successfully) in MSSql)

Q: How can I provide the desired result?
Redirections to suitable Documentation appreciated (so far I found docs only about other aspects of nesting, which do seem to relate to my question).

[Edit]
Attached see sample data of the inner select. The marked values in time_grouped are supposed to get grouped, the min(distance) to remain as value.
(Of course the not-marked rows will remain as well.)
So instead of 26 rows the result set should contain 15 rows.

[image: resultset]

Comment: Do you have some example data that the inline view creates? Would be easier to debunk if we could see some of that.

Comment: If you could also provide the results you are actually getting, vs the results you expect, that would also help

Comment: ah, sorry: the returned result is just 1 row: the mac (there is just 1), time_gouped=2147483647, and mdist=8871920. So mdist is actually the total minimum of all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datatyping problem.

What is the datatype of `rectime`?

Notice that `2147483647` is 2^31-1, as if somewhere a big number were truncated to a signed 32 bit `INT`.

When a `DATETIME` is used in arithmetic, it is converted to. say, 20170112151722:

```
mysql> SELECT NOW(), 0+NOW(), TO_SECONDS(NOW());
+---------------------+----------------+-------------------+
| NOW()               | 0+NOW()        | TO_SECONDS(NOW()) |
+---------------------+----------------+-------------------+
| 2017-01-12 15:17:22 | 20170112151722 |       63651453442 |
+---------------------+----------------+-------------------+
```

You should convert the time to a "unix timestamp" in order to treat it as seconds from some starting point (1970, in MySQL's case):

```
mysql> SELECT NOW(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
+---------------------+-----------------------+------------------+
| NOW()               | UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) | UNIX_TIMESTAMP() |
+---------------------+-----------------------+------------------+
| 2017-01-12 15:19:34 |            1484263174 |       1484263174 |
+---------------------+-----------------------+------------------+
```

This *still* does not explain the problem.  Please provide the output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ver%';`.  I want to see the exact version *and* whether it is a 32-bit build.  While you are at it, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE MyData;`.

Comment: Rick, using UNIX_TIMESTAMP solves the problem :-) True, it does not explain it, though. btw: version = 10.1.9-MariaDB; compile_machine=x64 and _os=Win64 (maria.org binary distribution).